# Does the relation $U=\sum_k \bar{n_k} \varepsilon_k$ hold in the classical limit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

Let's rewrite entropy in terms of $\bar{n}_k$ (average number of particles in the energy state k) supposing $U=\sum_k \bar{n}_k \varepsilon_k$ (where $\varepsilon_k$ is the energy of the k-th state):

$$\ln(Z)=\alpha N + \ln(\mathcal{Z})$$

(where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the grand partition function). We use the fact that $N=\sum_k \bar{n}_k$:

$$\ln(Z)=\alpha N + \ln(\Pi_k((1\pm e^{-\alpha-\beta\varepsilon_k})^{\pm1}))=\sum_k\Bigg(\alpha \bar{n}_k\mp \ln( \frac{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}}{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}\pm1})\Bigg)=\sum_k \bigg(\alpha \bar{n}_k \mp \ln(1\mp \bar{n_k})\bigg)$$

where the last equality comes from $\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}}{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}\pm 1} =e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}\bar{n}_k = \mp (\frac{1\mp (e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}\pm 1)}{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}\pm1})=1\mp \bar{n}_k$. Now let's use the relation

$$-k_BT\ln(Z)=F=U-TS \implies k_B(\ln(Z)+\beta U) = S$$

Using $\sum_k \bar{n}_k\varepsilon_k = U$ we get

$$S=k_B \sum_k \Bigg( \alpha \bar{n}_k \mp \ln(1\mp\bar{n}_k) + \beta \varepsilon_k \bar{n}_k\Bigg) = k_B \sum_k \Bigg( (\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k) \bar{n}_k \mp \ln(1\mp\bar{n}_k) \Bigg)$$
$$=k_B\sum_k\bigg(\ln(\frac{1\mp \bar{n}_k}{n_k})\bar{n_k}\mp \ln(1\mp\bar{n}_k)\bigg)$$
where we used the relation $\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k = \ln(e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k}) = \ln(\frac{e^{\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k} \bar{n}_k}{\bar{n}_k})=\ln(\frac{1\mp\bar{n}_k}{\bar{n}_k})$. In the classical limit, $\bar{n}_k<<1$ so we get

$$S=- k_B\sum_k \ln(\bar{n_k})\bar{n}_k$$
which approaches zero if $\bar{n}_k << 1$ (or equivalently as $e^{\alpha + \beta\varepsilon_k}>>1$) which obviously doesn't make sense. I couldn't find any mistakes in my reasoning except that I'm not sure about the use of $U=\sum_k \bar{n}_k \varepsilon_k$. This problem does not occur if $S$ is found using $S=-\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$ which does not rely on the previous assumption...

Comment: The problem is I see no reason why this relation would not hold in the classical limit, I'm really at loss why I got this result...

Comment: What you are doing here is taking the limit that the number of particles goes to zero, in which case it is not surprising that the entropy vanishes. What you seem to be trying to do is take the limit that the density goes to zero, so letting number of sites go to infinity while imposing the constraint that the number of particles $N=\sum_k n_k$ remains finite. This is probably quite fiddly in your current formulation